# Chess combination

Tags: combinatorics

On the chess board 8x8, we have 8 Rooks that , each Rook don't atack the other. How many situation if we give out:
 a) 1 main diagonal
 b) 2 main diagonals
That's mean we can't put the Rook to the cells of diagonal

Comment: I'm too young to understand the solution what you means .
I need the solution with combination or conformable, a simple solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want to count the number of ways of placing $n$ non-attacking rooks on an $n \times n$ chessboard (with some squares that the rooks must avoid), you can do it by calculating the [permanent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) of a $(0,1)$-matrix: we place a $1$ wherever a rook is allowed to go, and a $0$ wherever the rook is not allowed to go.

Calculating the permanent of $(0,1)$-matrices is a [#P-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_is_sharp-P-complete) problem.  So we cannot, in general, expect a simple "one size fits all" formula for these problems.

Here's [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code that solves the counting problem:

```
Permanent(
[[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]]
);
```

gives 14833 which is the number of [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) (as previously mentioned; see also Sloane's [A000166](http://oeis.org/A000166)).  It is also the number of $2 \times 8$ [Latin rectangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_rectangle) whose first row is $(0,1,\ldots,7)$.  In this instance, there's fairly simple formulae (see the links).

For the second question:

```
Permanent(
[[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
 [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1],
 [1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],
 [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1],
 [1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],
 [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1],
 [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]]
);
```

yields 4752 possibilities.  This is also the number of $3 \times 8$ Latin rectangles whose first row is $(0,1,\ldots,7)$ and second rows is $(7,6,\ldots,0)$.

Comment: 4752 is also the number of ways to place 3 non-attacking knights on a $6\times6$ board, according to http://oeis.org/A172134. Coincidence, presumably. The entry directly relevant to this question is http://oeis.org/A003471

Answer (score 7):

For (a), you want to count the permutations $\pi$ of $[1 \ldots 8]$ such that have no fixed point, i.e. $\pi(i) \ne i$ for all $i$.  These are also known as derangements.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

EDIT: For (b), see http://oeis.org/A003471